# fullcalendar: Get the selected time in Week View

Tags: fullcalendar

In the Week View, if I select a time period, how do I get the selected time, on the click of a button. Is there a function to call like, getTime or something?
I can get the selected day, by doing something like:

var start = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').visStart;

however, not sure how to get the selected time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `select` callback works better than `dayClick`, because you can get the start date if a range of dates were selected.

```
select: function(startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
  // here startDate and endDate will give you the date-range selected
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. On the select callback, i was able to get the selected start time and the selected end time. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

`visStart` property only keeps date object of the first visible day.

If you want get clicked date and time you may use dayClick event:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    //some code here
}
```

which has `date` as date object